# jquery doesn't remove div always on mouseleave

Tags: jquery

This is very annoying. After you rollover on image, if you rollout from left, top or right edges red box disappears. But if you rollout from bottom edge red box sometimes disappears sometimes not. Why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/f98r3/2/

***Edit:***
Another weird thing is, when you check console log, mouseleave fires but doesn't remove div!!!.

***Edit 2:***
Ok both answers solved the problem but still I wonder how on earth console.log logs the mouseleave in the original code but doesn't trigger remove()?

Comment: Have you learned any more about this? I'm trying to track down a similar but intermittent problem where a table row (tr) doesn't get removed. I discovered that your jsfiddle also fails even if you replace jQuery's .remove() with a call to JavaScript's .removeChild(). (http://jsfiddle.net/f98r3/29/) But it works if you delay the call to .remove() by using setTimeout(). (http://jsfiddle.net/f98r3/33/) This makes me think it might be related to the fact that the remove is being done in a callback from the system. In my case, the callback is the Ajax response, so maybe it's similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: block` for image solves the problem

Comment: ok this solved the problem but still I wonder how on earth console.log logs the mouseleave in the original code but doesn't trigger remove()

Answer (score 1):

I think that the outer div creates some problem, this way it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/f98r3/5/

```
$("img").bind("mouseenter", function () {
    $("#enlargemag").remove();
    var imgobj = this;
    var w = $(imgobj).width();
    var h = $(imgobj).height();
    var p = $(imgobj).position();
    $("<div id='enlargemag' style='border:none;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:" + p.top + "px;left:" + p.left + "px;width:" + w + "px;height:" + h + "px;background-color:#FF0000;'></div>").appendTo("body");
});
$("#enlargemag").live("mouseleave", function () {
    console.log("mouselave");
    $("#enlargemag").remove();
});
```

Comment: ok this solved the problem too but still I wonder how on earth console.log logs the mouseleave in the original code but doesn't trigger remove()